# Is there a configuration I could modify so that I don't have to ⌃Space first to trigger IntelliSense for "markdown" in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55438412/11074017) and [official doc,](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) and reproduced what they are saying.

To trigger IntelliSense for "markdown", I have to ⌃Space first, and then type the prefix-keyword, which is boring.

Is there a configuration I could modify so that I don't have to ⌃Space first to trigger IntelliSense for "markdown"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable suggestions as you type (quick suggestions), in your settings json file [set](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings):

```
"[markdown]": {
     "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": true
    }
}
```

Quick suggestion are disabled by default for markdown. The `[markdown]`language specific setting block lets you override this default and re-enable them.

If you enable quick suggestions in markdown, you may want to disable suggestions for words in the file as well by setting: `"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false`